# Does parsecs times arcsec/yr equate to any specific unit?

Tags: astronomy, units

Basically, I wanted to know if one multiplies proper motion (in arcsec/yr) to a distance (in parsecs), without conveting it to km/s (not multiplying it by 4.74, the conversion rate), does it equate to a known unit?

Comment: There is no concept of “known units”. You can multiply and divide units to make new ones *ad infinitum*. Your unit is a parsec-arcsec/yr.

Comment: One parsec-arcsecond per astronomical year **is** [4.740 km/s](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281+parsec%29%2A%28pi%2F%28180%2A3600%29%29%2A%281%2F%28365.25+days%29%29). What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally clear what you are asking. But a pc/Myr is very nearly a km/s.

Comment: so, what I mean is while calculating the transverse velocity of a moving object using proper motion and its distance when given in arcsec/yr and pc respectively, can we just multiply the two? (obviously we can, but is the result a known unit?)

Comment: @cutus_low It's $4.85\times 10^{-6}$ pc/yr or 4.74 km/s.   ??